# How to work with mapping dtos to domain in groovy?

Tags: groovy, automapper

I'm making a Grails project. I have lots of DTOs that I want to map to Domain objects. Is there a way to make this in groovy like Automapper from .Net? I think that the language can help a lot making this kind of mapping.

Comment: Have you tried mapping DTOs by adding hibernate mappings [as mentioned here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html)? If you have access to db then you can very well use [db reverse engineering](http://www.grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer) plugin to create your domain class and port additional functionality from DTOs to domain classes.

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro, but it's not the way Automapper is written. Perhaps I'll end making something like it. I'll let you know.